# Render Sign In With Google button react native expo

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, expo, google-signin

I am trying to use expo google siginin. However I cannot find how to render the signin button itself. *How do I get the actual button to render in my view?*

I am using this doc: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/google/

Answer (score 4):

Expo doesn't provide the button for you. You can use `react-native-elements`. They have a `SocialIcon` component, which does exactly what you need. Just give it `type={"google"}` as a prop.

```
<SocialIcon
  title={"Sign In With Google"}
  button={true}
  type={"google"}
/>
```

More about the component [here](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/social_icon.html).

Comment: Good solution-- just don't need the curly braces around the strings and you can just have "button" rather than "button = {true}". Also probably need an onPress in there.